# Is there a REST-based Web Service for returning the images found in a Web page?

Tags: web-services, rest

I am looking for something like Facebook's submit status feature, that when detects a URL, shows a thumbnail of all related images for that URL to the user. Does such a Web Service exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a service called [embed.ly](http://www.embed.ly) that can fetch the images and more. It has multiple APIs and the one that can be used for this purpose is called Extract.